# How can I test a Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Streams application that uses Avro and the Confluent Schema Registry?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I am having trouble figuring out how to test a Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Streams application that uses Avro as message format and a (Confluent) schema registry.

The configuration could be something like this:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: shipping-service
  cloud:
    stream:
      schema-registry-client:
        endpoint: http://localhost:8081
      kafka:
        streams:
          binder:
            configuration:
              application:
                id: shipping-service
              default:
                key:
                  serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$IntegerSerde
              schema:
                registry:
                  url: ${spring.cloud.stream.schema-registry-client.endpoint}
              value:
                subject:
                  name:
                    strategy: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.RecordNameStrategy
          bindings:
            input:
              consumer:
                valueSerde: io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerde
            order:
              consumer:
                valueSerde: io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.GenericAvroSerde
            output:
              producer:
                valueSerde: io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerde
      bindings:
        input:
          destination: customer
        order:
          destination: order
        output:
          destination: order

server:
  port: 8086

logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.kafka.config: debug
```

**NOTES:**

- It is using native serialization/deserialization.
- Test framework: Junit 5

I guess regarding the Kafka Broker I should use a EmbeddedKafkaBroker bean, but as you see, it also relies on a Schema Registry that should be mocked in some way. How?

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/bakdata/fluent-kafka-streams-tests/tree/master/schema-registry-mock#as-a-standalone-module

Comment: I was hoping for a Spring Cloud Stream way to mock the Schema Registry. I'll give it a go anyway.

Comment: One problem that I see is that whereas the application expects a configuration property with the url of the schema registry at some bean definition points (`@Value("\${spring.cloud.stream.schema-registry-client.endpoint}") endpoint: String`), this library provides it at runtime `this.getSchemaRegistryUrl()`

Comment: How are you loading the bootstrap servers? Could you define the registry address similarly?

Comment: I think I could set the `spring.cloud.stream.schema-registry-client.endpoint` property the same way it's done with the boostrap servers here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/blob/master/kafka-streams-samples/kafka-streams-word-count/src/test/java/kafka/streams/word/count/KafkaStreamsWordCountApplicationTests.java#L68

Comment: Couldn't get anyware with this, I'm using Junit5 and the equivalent @BeforeAll method is never called...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorting this out has been a real pain, but finally I managed to make it work using [fluent-kafka-streams-tests](https://github.com/bakdata/fluent-kafka-streams-tests/tree/master/schema-registry-mock):

**Extra dependencies:**

```
testImplementation("org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka-test")
testImplementation("com.bakdata.fluent-kafka-streams-tests:schema-registry-mock-junit5:2.0.0")
```

The key is to set up the necessary configs as System properties. For that I created a separated test configuration class:

```
@Configuration
class KafkaTestConfiguration(private val embeddedKafkaBroker: EmbeddedKafkaBroker) {

    private val schemaRegistryMock = SchemaRegistryMock()

    @PostConstruct
    fun init() {
        System.setProperty("spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers", embeddedKafkaBroker.brokersAsString)
        System.setProperty("spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.brokers", embeddedKafkaBroker.brokersAsString)
        schemaRegistryMock.start()
        System.setProperty("spring.cloud.stream.schema-registry-client.endpoint", schemaRegistryMock.url)
        System.setProperty("spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.schema.registry.url", schemaRegistryMock.url)
    }

    @Bean
    fun schemaRegistryMock(): SchemaRegistryMock {
        return schemaRegistryMock
    }

    @PreDestroy
    fun preDestroy() {
        schemaRegistryMock.stop()
    }
}
```

Finally the test class, where you can now produce and consume Avro messages with your KStream processing them and taking advantage of the mock schema registry:

```
@EmbeddedKafka
@SpringBootTest(properties = [
    "spring.profiles.active=local",
    "schema-registry.user=",
    "schema-registry.password=",
    "spring.cloud.stream.bindings.event.destination=event",
    "spring.cloud.stream.bindings.event.producer.useNativeEncoding=true",
    "spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.application.server=localhost:8080",
    "spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.event.consumer.keySerde=io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerde",
    "spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.event.consumer.valueSerde=io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerde"])
class MyApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var embeddedKafka: EmbeddedKafkaBroker

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var schemaRegistryMock: SchemaRegistryMock

    @Test
    fun `should process events`() {
        val senderProps = KafkaTestUtils.producerProps(embeddedKafka)
        senderProps[ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG] = "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer"
        senderProps[ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG] = "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer"
        senderProps["schema.registry.url"] = schemaRegistryMock.url
        val pf = DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<Int, String>(senderProps)
        try {
            val template = KafkaTemplate(pf, true)
            template.defaultTopic = "event"
            ...

    }
```